# Comparison of letters and strings in C++

Tags: c++, string-comparison

Why this code

```
if ("j" > "J")
```

return false, but this:

```
string a = "j";
string b = "J";

if (a > b)
```

return true? Which is the correct answer and how can i fix it?

Comment: `"j"` and `"J"` are pointers, so you're comparing their addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happenig because "j" and "J" are const char []. For exampe "j" is array of chars that 
c[0]='j' and c[1]='\0'. In C and C++ you can't compare two arrays.
it is better to use

```
strcmp("j","J");
```

witch is in

When you type

```
string a="j"
```

you run constructor in class string. But in class string you have overloaded operator< to compare two strings.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `"j"` and `"J"` are string literals, which are compared as `const char` pointers. The result of the comparison is therefore arbitrary, because the placement of literals in memory is implementation defined.

On the other hand, when you make `std::string` objects from these string literals, the `<` operator (along with other comparison operators) is routed to an override provided by the `std::string` class. This override does a lexicographic comparison of the strings, as opposed to comparing pointer values, so the results of comparison look correct.

Comment: "string literals, which are implemented as const char pointers" - not actually true, they just decay to const char pointers for the `<` comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You can use single quotes to compare symbols: `if ('j' > 'J')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if ("J" < "j")
```

and may be get a different result.

In fact "J" and "j" are constant C strings and may be placed on .data or .text sections which is determined by the output binary file format. So when you compare them, you are comparing their address in the memory.

But std::string is a C++ class which overloads the **>** operator, so it's not address/pointer comparing but content comparing.